# Spring Security + CDI/Inject

Tags: java, spring-security, cdi

Im building an applications with JSF + Hibernate + CDI + Spring Security.

I want to know if there is anyway to Inject DaoService into Spring Security custom provider, because this doesnt seems to work. The object always returns null, when i try to @Inject inside my login provider class (authentication-provider).

Thanks in advance,
Alexandre Rocco

Comment: Are you using a library to bridge CDI and Spring?  There have been a few attempts, but can't think of any trying spring security.

Comment: Honestly, if you're starting a new app, avoid mixing up CDI and Spring. Go for a full Spring Stack or a full CDI / Java EE where you can replace Spring Security by JBoss PicketLink : http://www.jboss.org/picketlink or Apache Shiro : http://balusc.blogspot.fr/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use EE utils from the Spring package to import ejbs into spring context as follows: 
`<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="ejb name" expected-type="tst.ExpectedClass"/>`